# Tomcat runs out of PermGen space, even with a lot of PermGen space reserved

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, out-of-memory, permgen

Running Tomcat fails with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`-errors related to lack of PermGen space.

I recently changed Tomcat to run as its own user (not root).

I have tried increasing the `PermGen` size in `CATALINA_OPTS` to 512MB and 1024MB, but it does not seem to have any effect.

I have also ruled out `ulimit` limitations by (temporarily) giving the user the same limitations as the root user has.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be lack of disk-space.

Tomcat and our application log/configuration files were on a partition that was almost completely full.

As the partition grew to completely full, our logging framework started throwing `IOException`s on attempts to write to the log files (rather than PermGen faults). The IOEXceptions gave me the hint i needed to solve the issue) Running `df` showed that the partition were completely full.

Moving the log files to another partition solves the problem and lets us run Tomcat as it's own (non-root) user.